# Options in res.render can only give 1 variable

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a problem with the res.render in express who render a ejs view, if I try this :

```js
res.render('index');
```

I don't have any problems, also if I do

```js
res.render('index', {foo:"bar"});
```

I still don't have any problems but if I do

```js
res.render('index', {foo:"bar", bar:"foo"});
```

all my vars will not be defined so someone have an idea how can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have a little more experience and I can just do:

```js
res.locals.foo = "bar";
res.locals.bar = "foo";
res.render("index");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
res.render("index", { data: { foo: "bar", bar: "foo" } })
```